# Sonarqube configuration in jenkins for windows

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate Sonarqube in Jenkins for windows.

I have installed Jenkins 2.138.2 and Sonarqube scanner plugin version 2.8.1

Also installed Sonarqube-7.3 and added it to path variable.

Below is my configuration in Jenkins:

- Under "Global Tool Configuration", for SonarQube Scanner
  installations - I have selected "Install automatically" and choose
  "Install from Maven Central".
- Under "Configure System", I have specified name and server url for
  Sonarqube servers.
- For the job, I have selected "Sonarqube analysis with Maven" under
  post build action step(shows this is deprecated).

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am getting the below error.

WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?
SonarQube analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube analysis with Maven' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube analysis with Maven' marked build as failure

Is there anything wrong with the configuration.

Edit: Added job configuration screenshots.

Comment: I have integrated it in Bamboo by using command task scripts which I think is called job in Jenkins and I believe the steps would be similar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277511/configure-sonar-in-bamboo). In case you have hosted the Sonar server locally and not using cloud then make sure it it up and running (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517190/not-able-to-compile-with-sonarsonar/52538167#52538167)

Comment: I have started sonarqube server and I can see that the service is running.

Comment: Could you add screen with the job configuration?

Comment: I have added job configuration screenshots.

Comment: Finally figured out that post build step has to be configured to execute sonarqube scanner and not in post build action.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading of sonarqube can be done form https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/ where downloading can be done irrespective to the requirements(here, downloading of Developers Version ver 7.4 is done)
a.  It will be downloaded in a zip format and will contain the sonarqube accessing file in various platforms, unzip the folder and extract all the files in your local system.

b.  Download the sonarqube scanner, it is helpful cause, it is the only way to start the code analysis, it is the most required or can be said as default launcher to analyse project with SonarQube.

c.  To start sonarqube, the start/open the startsonar.bat file.

d.  The sonarqube can be runs in default 9000 port.

e.  Launch sonarqube locally in the system.